# Formato de div para lista

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando conseguir poder hacer un formato para una lista que se generará mediante un `ng-repeat`. Quiero conseguir algo asi (De ante mano pido perdon por mi pesimo diseño, es que soy pesimo en css xD)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde esos circulos serán imagenes de usuario que ya tengo asi que no tengo problema.

El asunto es que he conseguido esto :

```html
<div style="width: 40px;height: 40px;background-color: red;float: left;margin-left: 15px;">
</div>
<div style="width: 40px;height: 40px;background-color: blue;float: left;margin-top: 25px;z-index: 1000;margin-left: -15px;">
</div>
<div style="width: 40px;height: 40px;background-color: red;float:right;margin-right: 15px;">
</div>
<div style="width: 40px;height: 40px;background-color: blue;float: right;margin-top: 25px;z-index: 1000;margin-right: -15px;">
</div>
```

No he podido poner el texto al lado de cada div.

Comment: No entiendo porque votaron para cerrar esta pregunta, está bastante claro que es lo que quiere el autor ... ¿alguna explicación o comentario para el voto?

Comment: Tal vez consideran que la imagen no es entendible ಠ_ಠ! , lo cual no es válido.

Comment: ¿cuál es el html del texto y en qué posición iría respecto al html de las imágenes?

Comment: eso es lo que no he logrado hacer @Shaz, necesito poder poner 1 texto por circulo, al lado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esto ayudará

```html
<div style="width: 40px;height: 40px;background-color: red;float: left;margin-left: 15px;">
  <div style="position: relative;right: -50px;width: 100px;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-60%)">Usuario 1</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 40px;height: 40px;background-color: blue;float: left;margin-top: 25px;z-index: 1000;margin-left: -15px;">
  <div style="position: relative;right: -50px;width: 100px;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-60%)">Usuario 2</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 40px;height: 40px;background-color: red;float:right;margin-right: 15px;">
  <div style="position: relative;left: -110px;width: 100px;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-60%); text-align: right; ">Usuario 3</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 40px;height: 40px;background-color: blue;float: right;margin-top: 25px;z-index: 1000;margin-right: -15px;">
  <div style="position: relative;left: -110px;width: 100px;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-60%); text-align: right; ">Usuario 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sería conveniente que incluyeras una breve descripción de cómo funciona el código que incluiste. Más detalles en [answer].